# Reparación de apps que contengan una implementación no segura de TrustManager

Tags: java, android

Alguien sabe sobre este mensaje, o que me puedan dar una idea mas especifica de que se trata, soy nuevo en esto de desarrollo de apps y estoy un poco perdido.

> "Esta información está dirigida a los programadores de aquellas apps
>   que contengan una implementación no segura de la interfaz
>   X509TrustManager. Específicamente, la implementación ignora todos los
>   errores de validación del certificado SSL cuando se establece una
>   conexión HTTPS con un host remoto, lo que provoca que tu app sea
>   vulnerable a ataques de intermediarios. Cualquier atacante podría leer
>   y hasta cambiar los datos transmitidos (como credenciales de acceso)
>   en la conexión HTTPS".

Comment: A ver, este fue un comunicado que envió Google a a quellos desarrolladores que tienen un (o varios) app en el store con una implementación insegura del `X509TrustManager` si eres nuevo en el desarrollo de apps ¿ya tienes un app en el store? ¿En dónde ves ese mensaje?

Comment: Rosendo, este comunicado te llego a tí? yo no lo había visto.

Comment: @Elenasys Personalmente a mí no, pero si a un colega. El tiene un app hecha Titanium Mobile. No tengo claro si es solo para ese caso o para Android nativo también. Aquí un link http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/02/google-security-alert-unsafe-implementation-of-the-interface-x509trustmanager/

Comment: ahora veo gracias por el link, también aplica para la aplicaciones nativas, si no estas seguro puedes entrar a la Developer Console y ahí se mostrara un indicador seguramente si alguna aplicación tiene este detalle.

Comment: Gracias compañeros, por sus comentarios, efectivamente este mensaje me llego por una app desarrollada en appcelerator, por ahora solo actualice mi sdk de compilación en appcelerator que por el post dejado en el enlace de arriba era una posible solución y si me funciono. Por otro lado en una app nativa que hace la misma conexión http usando volley no me salio ninguna advertencia de seguridad al momento de subirla a google play.

Answer (score 2):

Se supone que los certificados X509 se usan para autenticar una aplicación que se conecta por sockets. Pero este aviso indica que si implementaste la interfaz  [X509TrustManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html) y tratas de realizar una conexión https, en realidad estara funcionando como http, lo cual implica una alerta cuando se envían datos sensibles.

Si tienes aplicaciones deberías revisar si tus aplicaciones tienen esta implementación en la [consola de desarrollo Google Play](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/).

No había visto este comunicado, pero es importante para los desarrolladores ya que si tienen este detalle, se bloquearía la publicación de sus aplicaciones o actualizaciones.

Comment: Si, acabo de confirmar que si aplica para todas las plataformas, no solo para Titanium. Y de hecho desde Marzo se supone que iniciaría el bloqueo de apps con este defecto.